# Controlling hardware functionality

Tags: java, android, hardware

In an Android application written in Java, I want to be able to turn on/off hardware features like GPS, WiFi, Bluetooth etc.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to be able to turn on/off hardware features like GPS, WiFi, Bluetooth... How can I do?

Generally speaking, you don't.

You are welcome to examine the `android.provider.System.Settings` class to see what you can and cannot control. Most of what you list you cannot control.